# ¿Cómo saber cuando se debe usar GROUP BY y cuando no hace falta? MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Mi duda es la siguiente, no se cuando y como debo usar un `group by` ya que hay algunos ejercicios que tengo hecho bien de cursores pero casi siempre fallo en no poner el **group by** o en ponerlo.

Comment: Buenas, puedes poner ejemplos de dónde tendrías problemas?

Comment: Buenas tardes, no tengo código, porque ya lo resolvimos en clase solo me gustaría saber cuando debo usar un ``group by`` a ser posibles, muchas gracias, pero te puedo compartir mi [carpeta de ejercicios](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vm89CcmojxBeVFtLssse_Ro1Qr4JD4R7?usp=sharing). @melolo :-)

Comment: Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp ,viene bien explicado y quizás puede resolverte las dudas

Comment: Vale muchas gracias ahora le hecho un ojo :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` a menudo se usa junto a instrucciones `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID), Country, City    
FROM Customers    
GROUP BY Country, City;
```

De este modo, obtienes una tabla con tres columnas (el contador, *Country* y *City*), y las filas de la tabla corresponden a cada una de las combinaciones "Country, City" que existen en la tabla *Customers*.

Esas combinaciones quedan reflejadas en las filas de esta nueva tabla que ahora se devuelve, y para cada combinación (fila) se incluye el resultado del `COUNT`, es decir, el número de veces que ocurre la combinación "Country, City" determinada.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, ahora si lo comprendo, cuando debo contar algo casi siempre necesitare un ``group by``.

Comment: De nada amigo, un saludo

Comment: Ya he puesto mi respuesta :-)

Answer (score 1):

Realmente, el `GROUP BY` está en cierta forma relacionado con las funciones de totales o agregación:

```
COUNT()
MAX()
MIN()
AVG()
SUM()
STD()
GROUP_CONCAT()
...
```

Que son funciones que afectan a más de una fila, a diferencia de:

```
LEAST()
GREATEST()
```

Que afectan únicamente a los datos de una única fila.

Si una de esas funciones de agregación o de totales las pones directamente, afectará a todas las filas de la tabla, o a las que determines con un `WHERE`. En cambio, hay situaciones en las que hay un dato de un determinado campo que se repite en varios registros y te interesa hacer grupos con esos diferentes valores que va tomando y no únicamente con el que puedas definir con un `WHERE`. En esos casos usas `GROUP_BY` y es totalmente compatible con un `WHERE`.

Si visualizas los registros como fichas, cada grupo sería un montón en el que el campo por el que hayas agrupado tiene el mismo valor. Pues la función de totales la aplicas a cada montón, obteniendo el resultado que corresponda para cada montón en una fila diferente.

Un ejemplo típico es el de, en un tabla `jugadores` con los tampos `equipo`, `jugador`, `puntos`, agrupar jugadores por equipos para obtener los puntos anotados por cada equipo:

```
SELECT equipo,SUM(puntos)
  FROM jugadores
  GROUP BY equipo;
```

Como puedes deducir, agrupar por jugador, que sería la clave primaria de esta tabla, no tendría mucho sentido, pues obtendrías tantos grupos como registros.

Tampoco debemos agrupar si lo que buscamos es una consulta de valores únicos, para eso está el `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT equipo
  FROM jugadores
  GROUP BY equipo;
```

Dará el mismo resultado que:

```
SELECT DISTINCT equipo
  FROM jugadores;
```

Pero a un coste computacional mucho más elevado.

Crea una nueva pregunta con algún caso concreto en el que te sorprenda utilizar `GROUP BY` y lo analizamos en detalle.

Comment: Muchas gracias :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### ¿Qué es la orden GROUP BY en MySQL?

Es un comando que sirve para agrupar filas que tienen el mismo valor.

Este comando se usa con la orden **SELECT** y las consultas con **GROUP BY** se consideran consultas agrupadas.

#### Sintaxis:

```
SELECT tuColumnas FROM tuTabla GROUP BY tuColumnas;
```

#### Ejemplos:

***1.*** Crear una tabla llamada ***alumnos(nombre,edad)***, una vez creada ***añade datos a la tabla*** y ***agrupa por nombre y edad***.

```
CREATE TABLE alumnos(
    nombre VARCHAR(30),
    edad INT
);

INSERT INTO alumnos VALUES('Pablo',15),
                          ('Maria',15),
                          ('Pablo',15),
                          ('José',14);
```

Ahora voy a realizar el **GROUP BY**:

```
SELECT nombre,edad FROM alumnos GROUP BY nombre,edad;
```

Una vez que ***realicemos la consultas saldrá lo siguiente***:

---

| nombre | edad |
| --- | --- |
| Pablo | 15 |
| Maria | 15 |
| José | 14 |

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/409)

---

***2.*** **Añade a la tabla alumnos**, un **alumno llamado Pablo** y que ***no tenga 15 años***, una vez insertado el dato, realiza una consulta la cual cuente todos los alumnos.

```
INSERT INTO alumnos VALUES('Pablo',16);
```

***La consulta:***

```
SELECT nombre,COUNT(*),edad FROM alumnos GROUP BY nombre,edad;
```

***Lo que devuelve:***

---

| nombre | edad | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pablo | 15 | 2 |
| Maria | 15 | 1 |
| José | 14 | 1 |
| Pablo | 16 | 1 |

---

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/410)